# How to get steamwebapi to return data

Tags: python, python-requests, steam-web-api

I'm trying to pull player stats for specific games. When I try to request data from the steam API, it throws an error. From what I have seen this URL format has worked for many others, I'm not sure why it throws errors.

```
import requests
key = ''
steamid = ''
r = requests.get(f'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v2/?appid=252490&key={key}&steamid={(steamid)}')
data = r.json()
print(data)
```

```
Returns: <Response [500]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you are using http.

Have you tried https?

You may need to pass the `verify=False` parameter in the `request.get` call.

Comment: making it HTTPS does not seem to change any results. making the verify parameter False outputs the same thing and also says verification is strongly advised.

Comment: I managed to make the request with http myself. But I noticed that I was only able to make queries that returned 200, when related to games(appid) that steamid had in the library. For example, I tried `271590`(GTA) with my steamid, I don't have this game, and got a 400. I also tried `570`(Dota) and got a 200, cause i have this one. After that I tried my friends steamid with `271590`(GTA) ang got 200. He has GTA in his library.

Comment: hmm, what do you mean 200, what app id did you use?

Comment: `271590` is the appid for GTA, `570` is the appid for Dota2. In my case, 200 and 400 was the status code i was getting when running the `requests.get()`. To check a game appid, just go for the game you want in steam library, you'll find it on the page url `https://store.steampowered.com/app/570/Dota_2/`